# Accessing URLs from a list in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to search a HTML document for links to articles, store them into a list and then use that list to search each one individually for their titles.

Comment: *Is this possible?* .... Why don't you try and tell us

Comment: Do you want to read the text?

Comment: I'm trying to get the program to read it and then find specific pieces of data and then print that.  So for each of the links, for example, find the title of each article to print it to the shell window

Comment: @Monique try to do a specific question. "Its this possible?" seems to be YES because you wrote the code.... maybe the question should be something like: "I wrote this code [add code], I tried XXXX things.. , and get this problem [add problem, log files, errors,etc...]. how can I solve it?"

Comment: Okay, I edited it to be more specific to my problem. Any suggestions?  @Shudy

Comment: @Monique it looks better now ^^ . But my help ends here. Cause In python I Can't help you. Hope you get a good answer. And remember, once you get the solution. Upvote de answer, and accept it if it worked for you. In this way, everyone who was the same problem will find the solution fast. See you!

Comment: So, did you check the HTML code you got from the server, it seems the server banned you program.I can open the url in Chrome but not in Python code.

Comment: I downloaded the HTML files in Python code so that I could find out what to use to find the titles: '<h1 class="content__headline js-score" itemprop="headline">... etc. @zoosuck Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean the HTML code you downloaded is different from the code when you open it in Chrome or Firefox. Did you check that and make sure they are the same?

Comment: No I didn't.  It prints the list article_links fine, it's just titles that doesn't work.  Do you think it is because I'm searching for the wrong thing with the findall function? @zoosuck

Comment: Maybe the server side banned you code so that you got nothing...

Comment: fine, you edit question and it's completely unclear what you need to achieve.  Where is the problem, code sample?

Comment: If I leave it there when I hand in my assignment the program we use will say I've plagiarised.  @Reishin

Comment: there nothing to be  plagiarized, that code even not work ^_^. And you to late, code is anyway stay in edit history

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly not direct answer for OP, but should not considered as off-topic:  **You should not parse web page for the html data**.

html web pages are not optimized to answer for a lot of requests, especially requests not from browsers. A lot of generated traffic could made servers overloaded and trigger DDOS.

So you need try to found any available API for interesting your site and only if nothing relative found, use parsing of web content with using cache of request to not overload target resource.

At the first look, `The Guardian` have [Open API](http://open-platform.theguardian.com/) with [documentation](http://open-platform.theguardian.com/documentation/) how to use.

Using that API you could work with site content in simply manner, making you interesting requests more easier and answers available without parsing.

For example, search by tag "technology" [api output](http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=technology&api-key=test):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import json
import sys

def safeprint(s):
  try:
    print(s)
  except UnicodeEncodeError:
    if sys.version_info >= (3,):
      print(s.encode('utf8').decode(sys.stdout.encoding))
    else:
      print(s.encode('utf8'))


url = "http://content.guardianapis.com/search?q=technology&api-key=test"

try:
  content = urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
  json_data = json.loads(content)
  if "response" in json_data and "results" in json_data["response"]:
    for item in json_data["response"]["results"]:
      safeprint(item["webTitle"])
except URLError as e:
  if isinstance(e, HTTPError):
    print("Error appear: " + str(e))
  else:
    raise e
```

Using that way you could walk through all publications in deep without any problem.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `Beautiful Soup` to parse the HTML and find the title tag in each page:

```
read = [urllib.urlopen(link).read() for link in article_links]
data = [BeautifulSoup(i).find('title').getText() for i in read]
```

Comment: I guess the OP is asking for the way of opening a given link and not about list comprehension here.

Comment: @anmol_uppal How is it now?

Comment: Why not process the data from each URL in a simple `for` loop? There's no need here to store all that data at once - there might be hundreds or thousands of URLs in `article_links`...